# Is it possible to take incremental back up of Database in Openerp?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

Daily I am able to take the back up of PostgreSQL Database in Openerp by using Cron job. Every day database dump is coming around 50 MB. I want to take it daily which means 50 mb each day, which will consume large amount to hard disk space. I don't want it to happen. I want to take incremental Database back up every day.Can any one help me.Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can delete the old backup after the successful completion of the latest backup right??

Comment: Yes you are correct.I'm suing openerp for a Medical project.so i need all the Database back up's.

Comment: am also using PostgreSQL for retail and wholesale medical shops

Comment: what am doing is  taking each day's backup in separate 7 folders,and removes the old backup when successful completion of latest backup that enough right ?? why keeping all backups in single disk or tell them to move   the old backup to another location(an external harddisk)

Comment: Just use proper backup aging. Keep the daily backup for the last 7 days, then the weekly for the last 3 months, then the monthly for the last 12 months, etc.

Comment: Thank's guys. But is there a possible to take incremental back up or not?

Comment: @nitesh "I'm suing openerp" ... you surely mean "using", right?

Comment: @DanielReis Yes you are correct,I'm sorry about that spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the backups to ensure OpenERP is compressing them.  If not you can do it manually or use pg_dump or pgadmin3 to do the backups.

If you want point in time backups then you will need to get tricky with postgres with check points and log shipping and I would think carefully before going down that road.

The other thing to note is OpenERP stores the attachments in the database so if you have a lot of attached documents or emails with attachments, these will be in the ir_attachments table and cause your backups to grow quickly.